# OR in django database queries

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model that has 3 BooleanFields, and I want to use a checkbox form to query the database. The output should be all the entries of the table that has as 1 at least one of the fields that where checked.
Right now I ahve something like this:

```
f=mform.cleaned_data['F']
h=mform.cleaned_data['H']
s=mform.cleaned_data['S']
course_list=[]
course_list=Course.objects.filter(Q(F=f)|Q(H=h)|Q(S=s))
```

But this clearly doesn't work, as it always returns all the table. Basically I want to get all Course records where any of these fields are True.
Any ideas?

Comment: These single letter variables and names are hard to read. Are you trying to say in english "All Course records where any of these fields are True"?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the ambiguous code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query: "select all Course records where (F is True OR H is True OR S is True)"**

```
q_filter = Q()

if mform.cleaned_data['F']:
    q_filter |= Q(F=True)
if mform.cleaned_data['H']:
    q_filter |= Q(H=True)
if mform.cleaned_data['S']:
    q_filter |= Q(S=True)

if q_filter:
    course_list = Course.objects.filter(q_filter)
else:
    course_list = Course.objects.none()
```

This is a pretty basic approach. It could be done in a fancier one line loop but I wanted to go for clarity here. You build up a Q object over time. In your example you are filtering for values that could be True or False, whereas you said what you wanted is to only filter records that have a given field with a True value.